# Servicestack.Client Namespace Secured could not be found

Tags: servicestack, refresh-token

When I try to make a new request to generate a new access-token I cannot find the type "new Secured".

```
var authClient = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost/authentication/")
            {
                RefreshToken = Request.GetCookieValue("ss-refreshtok"),
                RefreshTokenUri = "http://localhost/authentication/access-token"
            };
            var jwt = authClient.Send(new Secured());
```

Even thought I have Servicestack.client installed it cannot be found. But using `new Authenticate()` its ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Secure` Request DTO is an example of a Request DTO for a Service that’s protected with the `[Authenticate]` attribute, it’s not a built in DTO, you should substitute it to use your Request DTO instead.